# SSH - What is AllowTcpForwarding "local"

Tags: linux, ssh

Currently I have some Linux servers with the `AllowTcpForwarding` set to "yes" in sshd_config file.

I have to change `AllowTcpForwarding` from "yes" to "local" in all the servers but I'm having a hard time understanding what those options mean. I don't know what this change can cause.

Can someone explain me the difference between those options?

Unfortunately we don't have a test environment so I could not change anything, I don't know what it will cause.

Comment: Why do you "have to" change the option? If you don't know what it does, why do you want to change it? What actual problem the change is supposed to solve? Have you read the [manual](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AllowTcpForwarding)? Where is describes `AllowTcpForwarding`, is there some part you think you understand? What part(s) don't you understand? Are you familiar with port forwarding in SSH in general? or are you totally fresh to the subject? Please answer these by [edit]ing the question, not in comments.

Comment: Do you understand that disabling TCP forward WILL NOT increase your security?  Do you understand the difference between, local from the perspective of ssh(1) TCP forwarding and allowing the all TCP forwarding?

Comment: @Tetsijin - Stupid internet cause me to accidently not select all that text. Thanks for the backup

Comment: Applicable chapter from ssh.com: https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling-example

Answer (score 1):

SSH supports forwarding connections in two directions:

- **local:** the SSH client listens on a client-side TCP port and the server connects to some destination on behalf of some client-side process;
- **remote:** the SSH client requests the *server* to listen on a server-side TCP port, and the *client* connects to some destination on behalf of some server-side process.

OpenSSH options `-L`, `-D`, and `-W` all use "local" forwarding; `-R` uses "remote" forwarding.